# PHP GD Library, how to paste text after another text block

Tags: php, image, text, gd, gdlib

I need to paste a text after another text using GD Library. [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz22S.png). I tried to do it the following way

```
$text = wordwrap($text, 80, "\n");
$count = substr_count($text, "\n");
$string_number = 14;
$pos = 0;
if ($count >= $string_number) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
        $pos = stripos($text, "\n", $pos) + 1;
    }
    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos);
    //Attempt to calculate coordinates of a text block
    $text_cord = imagettfbbox(14, 0, $font_300_path, $text);
    //And paste text after the end coordinate
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 130, $text_cord[3], $blue, font_300_path, 'Need to paste');
 }

imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 130, 293, $black, $font_300_path, $text);
```

But if I do it this way I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpAl0.png)

So, my question is, how can I paste a text after the other text block?

Comment: You mean paste?

Comment: Oh, yes! Fixed.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please paste all the code you are using to create the image so your problem can be reproduced. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just used `font_size * line_height * number_of_new_lines` to find end coordinates